# SonataAdminBundle new block type

Tags: symfony, block, sonata-admin

Did anybody create new block type for SonataAdminBundle using extend bundle? I'm trying to do so but it only works if I add service directly in original `block.xml`. Anything change in `block.xml` under `config` directory in MyBundle (extended SonataAdminBundle) has no effect.

Any one has solution? Plz help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your XML file is correctly loaded in your own bundle?

It must be done in the `load()` method declared in file `MyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyBundleExtension.php`:

```
$loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('block.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I did exactly like that but no result.

Comment: Hurray! I did a mistake, exactly, it works by your solution. Thanks Vincent!